# How to find any data from a column in a cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to have a range as a search key in google sheets? Like some sort of IF CONTAINS?

For example:
If column A contains any data listed in Column B, then it should return TRUE else FALSE.

| Column A | Column B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a02,bw2,z2 | a01 | FALSE |
| z12,x9e,df | b22 | FALSE |
| xz8,aa2,mn | wc2 | TRUE |
| a01,sr8,xf | xz8 | TRUE |
| +1K rows | +1K rows | +1K rows |

Tried REGEXMATCH, MATCH, LOOKUPS, FIND but no luck. Tried a range(like the whole column) as a search key, but it kind of concatenates the whole data in the column and uses the whole column as the search key. What I need is for it to use the data in column A as separate search keys. Since there are thousands of data, it would be time consuming to IF VLOOKUP each data.

Answer (score 0):

Use formula:

```
=if(sumproduct(arrayformula(split(A1,",")=$B$1:$B$4)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

It splits value in `A1` to 3 elements array and compares it to every value in column B you give. It returns 2 dimension array with TRUE or FALSE (this case array is 3x4). `SUMPRODUCT` of this array will be positive number if at least one value is TRUE.

Result:
[image]